# Appium :Element Not Visible Exception while automating Hybrid App

Tags: android, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate Selendroid's test App .

That has a Hybrid View.

Even after changing the context,I am not able to perform any activity on the WebView.

Test App: /selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk from Selendroid UI

Appium Version: 1.6.5

**Script:**
 driver.findElementById("io.selendroid.testapp:id/buttonStartWebview").click();

```
    Set<String> views = driver.getContextHandles();


    Iterator it=views.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }

    driver.context("WEBVIEW_io.selendroid.testapp");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Current view is"+driver.getContext());

    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='name_input']")).sendKeys("test");;
```

**Eclipse Log**

---

[TestNG] Running:

NATIVE_APP
WEBVIEW_io.selendroid.testapp
Current view isWEBVIEW_io.selendroid.testapp

```html
<html><head><title>Say Hello Demo</title></head><body>Hello, can you please tell me your name?<form name="myform" action="http://localhost:4450/sayhello" method="get"><div align="center"><br><br><input type="text" id="name_input" name="name" size="25" value="Enter your name here!"><br><p>Prefered Car:<br><select name="car"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select></p><br><input type="submit" value="Send me your name!"><br></div></form><iframe name="chromedriver dummy frame" src="about:blank"></iframe></body></html>
```

FAILED: f
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: webview=30.0.0.0)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'INHYIZLP06494', ip: '10.7.60.141', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=D:\RnD\WorkspaceDev\Appium\AUT\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk, appPackage=io.selendroid.testapp, deviceScreenSize=1280x720, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=io.selendroid.testapp, appWaitActivity=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=emulator-5554, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=emulator-5554, appActivity=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity, desired={app=D:\RnD\WorkspaceDev\Appium\AUT\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk, platformName=Android, deviceName=emulator-5554}, platformVersion=4.4.2, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=SM-G900F, platformName=Android, deviceManufacturer=samsung}]
Session ID: 9b4cd26a-1d77-4087-8ce9-d87fbdef24e0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:33)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement.execute(AndroidElement.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
    at HybridApp.SelendroidTestHybrid.f(SelendroidTestHybrid.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

---